# Where are you at this time

Tags: time

Where are you if,

- When it's 10 o'clock, it's 2 o'clock
- When it's 5 o'clock, it's 7 o'clock

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> *Through the Looking Glass*, with Alice Liddell?  (Everything is mirror images).              
> [image: Reflection of clock showing how 10 o'clock is 2 o'clock] 
> (Illus. dedicated to @A. I. Breveleri and all the youngsters who are analogously impaired.)

Comment: Sniped by under 5 seconds :D

Comment: :) Glad I didn't take the time to mock up some images for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Was just trying to find an image of a broken clock with a mirror placed strategically....sigh :(

Comment: I wonder how many young people, who are familiar with only digital clocks, cannot understand this answer even when it is explained to them.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri: .eviecer llahs ey dna ksa

Answer (score 2):

> In a mirror, because reading a clock with hands in reverse gives 10 = 12 - 2 and 5 = 12 - 7.